# conditional linking in GCC

Tags: c++, c, linker, pragma

In MSVC it's possible to write:

```
// in Lib.h
#if USE_OLD_LIB

    #pragma comment(lib, "old_lib.lib")
    #include "old_lib.h"

#else

    #pragma comment(lib, "new_lib.lib")
    #include "new_lib.h"

#endif
```

How can I do this without having the pragma comment support in GCC?

Edit: I know it's possible to use a make file, but the USE_OLD_LIB conditional macro is connected to some logic inside another library like the following:

```
// in Lib2.h
#if OBJ_SIZE > 20
#define USE_OLD_LIB
#endif
```

So, it would be a hassle to use a make file for it.

Comment: How are you building with gcc? If you are using a makefile then you can set the define on the command line and have the makefile conditionally link in the appropriate lib.

Comment: I know it's possible to use a makefile, the problem is the USE_OLD_LIB is connected to some logic in another library. like the following 
#if OBJ_SIZE > 20
#define USE_OLD_LIB
#endif

Comment: You should update your question with all the relevant facts and constraints.

Comment: Is this impossible to do with GCC? Why is nobody answering this question?

Comment: I'll say it - it is not possible with gcc.